# How do I Get Stack Trace from LogRecord in Python?

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

I am implementing a custom Handler with Python. Naturally, I need to override `emit(self, record)` to do that. An example:

```py
from logging import Handler, LogRecord

class FooHandler(Handler):
    def emit(self, record: LogRecord):
        # handler logic
```

As you can see, everytime I log something with a `Logger` instance, this will provide a `LogRecord` to `emit` method.

I see the current implementation of `LogRecord` from CPython source, you can also see it from [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L272).

Assuming I have `Logger` instance called `logger`. Later somewhere in the code, I do these:

```py
# either this
logger.exception(Exception("foo"))
# it does not have to be an instance of Exception, it's for the sake of simplicity

# or this
logger.error("foo", exc_info=True)
# this also provides a stack trace on the console handler
```

Since @thebjorn has commented about [traceback](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/traceback.html) module, I think I can work around from that. However I have three questions right now:

1. How do I get the exception from `LogRecord` instance?
2. If I do `logger.error("message", exc_info=True)`, then I do not pass any exception instance. In this case, how do I get the traceback since I do not simply have any exception instance?

Thanks in advance.

## Environment

- Python 3.5 and above

Comment: the `traceback` module..?

Comment: Actually, `SteamHandler` implementation has given me a bit of insight but I still might need an explanation about [handleError](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L987).

Comment: @thebjorn, that was what I was looking for. I didn't know such a thing existed in standard library.

Answer (score 1):

I am the OP and this may not be the best answer, in practice or more Pythonic way but, for Googlers, there is a method.

As [@thebjorn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/75103/thebjorn) stated in the comments of the question, you need [traceback](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html) built-in module.

Then you need to make sure that the exception you are targeting is the latest exception your software has raised. Then you can simply call:

```
traceback.print_last()
```

If there is no exception, then you will get below as a string:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/traceback.py", line 173, in print_last
    raise ValueError("no last exception")
ValueError: no last exception
```

In other case, you will get the latest exception's traceback:

```py
raise Exception("foo")
traceback.print_last()

# will return a string similar to below

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/foo/bar/baz.py", line 3296, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "/foo/bar/biz.py", line 1, in <module>
    raise Exception("foo")
Exception: foo
```

Hope this helps to Googlers.

## Things to Be Aware Of

As I've mentioned, you will need to *make sure* that the last exception that has got raised is the exception that you are targeting. This might not be a viable solution

- **for multithreaded codebase** because you must be extra careful about which thread your code is running on or
- **a codebase that is structured upon a framework such as Django** because the exception handling of such frameworks might be quite complex and you might get a different Exception rather than the one you were excepting to get

Comment: If there's not any answer with detail and with different approach in two days, I will accept this answer as valid.

Answer (score 1):

The LogRecord object has an `exc_text` attribute that looks to be identical to the text provided in a traceback. It returns `None` when there isn't an exception.

So I think the following would get the OP what they were originally requesting:

```
from logging import Handler, LogRecord

class FooHandler(Handler):
    def emit(self, record: LogRecord):
        print(record.exc_text)
        # other handler logic
```

Answer (score 1):

Expanding upon sazerac's code, exec_text didn't have any value when I ran it with a sample try except block, but exc_info WAS populated. This is what I used to work around my scenario.

```
from logging import Handler, LogRecord
import traceback

class FooHandler(Handler):
    def emit(self, record: LogRecord):
        if record.exc_info:
            errType, errValue, errTraceback = record.exc_info
            msg = "".join(traceback.format_exception(errType, errValue, errTraceback))
        else:
            msg = ''
        print(msg)
```